# prove that a set is infinite

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $\mathbb{N}\le X$, show that X is infinite. (Hint assume X is finite and derive a contradition)

$''\le''$ means here less than or equinumerous with

Proof: (I am a beginner in the set theory)...

Assume X is finite, i.e $\exists f:n\to X$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ which is bijective and then $\exists f^{-1}:X\to n$ which is also bijective. 
By the hypothesis $\mathbb{N}\le X$ which means that $\exists g:\mathbb{N}\to X$ which is injective.

But how to derive a contradition now?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there.

**Hint:** What do we know about $f^{-1} \circ g: \Bbb N \to n$?

Comment: @Heidi: Or about $g^{-1}\circ f$; you can get your contradiction from either.

Comment: $f^{-1}\circ g: \mathbb{N}\to n$ is a composition of bijective (and thus injective) and other injective function which gives an injective function, but then it means that $\mathbb{N}\le \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Almost correct. It means that $\Bbb N \le n$. But...

Comment: ah ok so then I will have that $\mathbb{N}\le n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ right?

Comment: Yes. Can you derive a contradiction from that?

Comment: I am not sure. This would mean that the set of naturals is less than or equinumerous with some natural number n. But as the set of naturals is infinite...then it is impossible right?

Comment: Indeed, but you will have to prove that. If you have proved that $n \simeq m$ implies $n = m$, then you could use $n+1\le \Bbb N$ and transitivity of $\le$ to establish it.

Comment: now everything is clear, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad you were willing to think along!